# I can't use gd=DETECT with graphics in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, bgi

The purpose of my program is to create a Snake game in C. It was my first time to ever have to use graphics.h, and apparently it wasn't in the include folder. I went ahead and downlaoded it and after reading many pages on how to use it I find out things like gd= DETECT, setcolor(WHITE), setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, con) don't work at all. Now for the colour related issues I found out I could write them as ints so this isn't an issue. But why isn't DETECT working??? Plugging in my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <graphics.h>


int m[500], n[500], con = 20;
clock_t start, stop;

check() {
int a;
for (a = 1; a < con; a++)

    if (m[0] == m[a] && n[0] == n[a]) end();
    else continue;

}
end()

{

int j, i;
setcolor(WHITE);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    delay(500);
    cleardevice();
    delay(500);
    for (j = 0; j <= con; j++) {
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, RED);
        circle(m[j], n[j], 5);
        floodfill(m[j], n[j], WHITE);
    }

}

settextstyle(3, 0, 4);
outtextxy(150, 150, "    GAME OVER ");
getch();
getch();
exit(0);
}

win()
{
int j, i;
setcolor(WHITE);
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j <= con; j++) {
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, con);
        circle(m[j], n[j], 5);
        floodfill(m[j], n[j], WHITE);
    }
    delay(500);
    cleardevice();
    delay(500);
}
settextstyle(3, 0, 4);
outtextxy(210, 320, " YOU WIN ");
getch();
exit(0);
}

int main()
{

int gd = DETECT, gm, ch, maxx, maxy, x = 13, y = 14, p, q, spd = 100;

initgraph(&gd, &gm, "..\bgi");

setcolor(WHITE);
settextstyle(3, 0, 6);
outtextxy(200, 2, " SNAKE 2 ");
settextstyle(6, 0, 2);
outtextxy(20, 80, " Use Arrow Keys To Direct The Snake ");
outtextxy(20, 140, "Avoid The Head Of Snake Not To Hit Any Part Of Snake");
    outtextxy(20, 160, " Pick The Beats Untill You Win The Game ");
outtextxy(20, 200, " Press 'Esc' Anytime To Exit ");
outtextxy(20, 220, " Press Any Key To Continue ");
ch = getch();
if (ch == 27) exit(0);
cleardevice();
maxx = getmaxx();
maxy = getmaxy();

randomize();

p = random(maxx);
int temp = p % 13;
p = p - temp;
q = random(maxy);
temp = q % 14;
q = q - temp;



start = clock();
int a = 0, i = 0, j, t;
while (1)
{

    setcolor(WHITE);
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, con + 5);
    circle(p, q, 5);
    floodfill(p, q, WHITE);

    if (kbhit())
    {
        ch = getch(); if (ch == 0) ch = getch();
        if (ch == 72 && a != 2) a = 1;
        if (ch == 80 && a != 1) a = 2;
        if (ch == 75 && a != 4) a = 3;
        if (ch == 77 && a != 3) a = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ch == 27
            ) break;
    }

    if (i < 20) {
        m[i] = x;
        n[i] = y;
        i++;
    }

    if (i >= 20)

    {
        for (j = con; j >= 0; j--) {
            m[1 + j] = m[j];
            n[1 + j] = n[j];
        }
        m[0] = x;
        n[0] = y;

        setcolor(WHITE);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, con);
        circle(m[0], n[0], 8);
        floodfill(m[0], n[0], WHITE);

        setcolor(WHITE);
        for (j = 1; j < con; j++) {
            setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, con + j % 3);
            circle(m[j], n[j], 5);
            floodfill(m[j], n[j], WHITE);
        }
        delay(spd);

        setcolor(BLACK);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLACK);
        circle(m[0], n[0], 8);
        floodfill(m[0], n[0], BLACK);

        setcolor(BLACK);
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL, BLACK);
        circle(m[j], n[j], 5);
        floodfill(m[j], n[j], BLACK);

    }
    stop = clock();
    t = (stop - start) / CLK_TCK;
    printf(" TIME %d sec   ", t);
    printf("SCORE %d",con-5);
        check();

    if (x == p && y == q) {
        con = con + 5; if (spd >= 5) spd = spd - 5; else spd = 5;
        if (con > 490) win();
        p = random(maxx); temp = p % 13;  p = p - temp;
        q = random(maxy); temp = q % 14;   q = q - temp;
    }
    if (a == 1)  y = y - 14; if (y < 0) { temp = maxy % 14; y = maxy - temp; }
    if (a == 2)  y = y + 14; if (y > maxy) y = 0;
    if (a == 3)  x = x - 13; if (x < 0) { temp = maxx % 13; x = maxx - temp; }
    if (a == 4)  x = x + 13; if (x > maxx) x = 0;
    if (a == 0) { y = y + 14;  x = x + 13; }
   }

   }
```

Comment: the file  `graphics.h` is a leftover from the days of DOS and 'shouldn't' be used in modern C programs

Comment: @user3629249 but I have an assignment to make a coloured Snake game... How else would I achieve this?

Comment: one possibility is the package `OpenGL`